# Access rootState within async effect without specifying payload first

Tags: reactjs, redux

Context:  I want to have an action that calls two other actions, so I made an effect.  Within this effect, I need to access the rootState.  I read that [the second argument of an effect must be the rootState](https://github.com/rematch/rematch/issues/854#issuecomment-757060466), but [if there are no arguments, the rootState is still passed to the effect](https://github.com/rematch/rematch/issues/854#issuecomment-757066409).

This works and will print out rootState (however I have no need for a payload):

```
effects: {
       async doThisAndThat(payload, rootState) {
            console.log(rootState);  // prints out rootState just fine
            rootState.doThis();
            rootState.doThat();
        },
}
```

This prints undefined for this.state:

```
effects: {
       async doThisAndThat() {
            console.log(this.state);  // prints undefined
            this.state.doThis();
            this.state.doThat();
        },
}
```

ALSO: it is possible that this is difficult because redux is not designed to be used in this way.  If so, I am happy to do it another way.  Any insights appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they mean is that even if your function has no arguments, it will still be called *with* arguments.  I'd imagine internally, redux has something like this:

```js
let rootState = { user: 'foo@bar.com' };

const callAction = (fn) => (payload) => {
    fn(payload, rootState)
}

function doThisAndThat() {
    const rootState = arguments[1];
    console.log('doThisAndThat', {rootState});
}

callAction(doThisAndThat)({ payload: 'ignore this' });
```

Where you can see `doThisAndThat` takes no arguments, but it is called *with* arguments, which you can still access by using the `arguments` magic variable.

All that being said, I'd just do

```
async doThisAndThat(_, rootState) {
```

to make it clear you don't care about the payload

Comment: Thanks @dave !  I just found another example of this in repo that does pretty much the same thing but with `unused` instead of `_`.